# how to scroll all images in icarousel

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to scroll all images in carousel view. But in my view the animation starts move when i scroll the middle image. If i touch the other images next to it, they don't move. I use buttons in viewForItemAtIndex method. Do you have any idea how can i move all images that are visible?

This is my viewForItemAtIndexMethod:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index    reusingView:(ReflectionView *)view
{


UIButton* button = nil;
if (view == nil)
{
    UIImage *image = [arrKitapKapaklari objectAtIndex:index];
    view = [[[ReflectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];

    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = 99;
    [view update];
    [view addSubview:button];

}
else
{
    button = (UIButton *)[view viewWithTag:99];
}


[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return view;
}
```

Comment: What is your iCarousel frame? You are initializing it via IB or in code?

Comment: I initialized in code. But i think it is about delegate methods of icarousel. I try to solve but i am newbie. I didn't understand the all methods

Comment: As I remember iCarousel has a pan gesture recognizer and it works on whole view. Can you post your code fragment where you setup carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is something wrong with your iCarousel frame - maybe touches on other elements are outside the frame and iCarousel gesture recognizers won't receive touches. Other possibility is that some other elements of your view catch touches and don't pass that to iCarousel. iCarousel is designed to handle all touches (not only from main element). As I wrote in comment below your post, are you sure everything is ok with your carousel setup?

Answer (score -1):

this is my code for the method you're dealing with (now I'm using images w/ labels under each image, the image are stored in an array).

```
    - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
   {

        if (index < [items count]) {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.hldImage objectAtIndex:index]]; 
            view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, image.size.height,image.size.width, 50)];
            NSString *carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[hldName objectAtIndex:index]];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.text = carName;
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
           label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
           label.numberOfLines = 99;
            [view addSubview:label];
            [view setTag:index+1];

        }
        return view;
    }
```

this is the code I have implemented to bring images to center (this is in the ICarousel.m)

```
- (void)didTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    NSInteger index = [self indexOfItemView:[tapGesture.view.subviews lastObject]];
    if (centerItemWhenSelected && index != self.currentItemIndex)
    {
        NSLog(@"tapped item not at center, index =  %i",index);
        [self scrollToItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
        NSUInteger tag =  index;
    }
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(carousel:didSelectItemAtIndex:)])
    {
        [delegate carousel:self didSelectItemAtIndex:index];
        NSUInteger tag =  index;
    }
    if (self.currentItemIndex)
    {
        NSLog(@"Current index item, index = %i",index);
    }
}
```

all my images in the Carousel have a tag associated with them.

Comment: This is not what i want. In my carousel view, 4 images are visible. To start animation i have to scroll center item. If i try to scroll other images it doesn't work. The animation doesn't start to move.

Comment: I added the method you have implemented.  you can ignore my labels b/c that's the text field under each image.. but hldImage is an array holding the images.